# <button onClick={setCount(count + 1)}>increase</button> why does this not work in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

been working with useState hook in reactjs where i tried to increase the value of count upon clicking the button. but nothing is rendered on my page, not even the button. Could you tell me how I fix it?

i tried using onclick handler which i thought would trigger the setCount function once the event is triggered, increasing the value of count by 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the code <button onClick={setCount(count + 1)}>increase is that you are invoking the setCount function immediately when rendering the component, rather than passing it as a callback function to the onClick event handler.

To fix this, you need to wrap the setCount function call in an arrow function or a callback function. Here's the corrected code:

```
<button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>increase</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use callback function in the onClick

```
<button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>increase</button>
```